# Excel - Unicode named cell range

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I have written a small function to expedite naming cells:

```
Public Sub InputSelectedNames()
    For Each Cell In Selection
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim strName As String
        strName = InputBox("Enter name for cell " & Cell.Address(False, False) & ":", "Name cell")
        If Len(strName) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:=strName, RefersTo:=Cell
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

This works great until I try to enter a unicode string as a name. If I enter something like "αβγ" it appears as "aß?" in the InputBox.

I've read about [VBA using ANSI encoding](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/) so I understand why this is the case. The example solution given in that tutorial works for displaying unicode (by passing a pointer instead of a string object), but I wasn't able to utilize the same idea for an InputBox.

If I enter these characters through Excel's 'Define Name' button on the formula tab, or through referencing the character in another cell it works fine, so the mistranslation definitely seems to lay in the InputBox.

My guess is that I'll have to make a Userform to handle the input, unless anyone knows a way to get InputBox to play nicely with unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a custom InputBox did solve this problem.

[image: Form layout]

```
frmInputBox : UserForm
lblOutput : Label providing prompt
txtInput : TextBox for input
cmdOK : CommandButton for accepting input
cmdCancel : CommandButton for aborting prompt
```

VBA Form Code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Accept
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Cancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel
End Sub

Private Sub txtInput_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Accept
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then
        Cancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Accept()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel()
    txtInput.Text = ""
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Public Function Prompt(strPrompt As String, Optional strTitle As String = "Input", Optional strDefault As String = "")
    With Me
        .Caption = strTitle
        .lblOutput.Caption = strPrompt
        .txtInput.Text = strDefault
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show
    End With

    If txtInput.Text <> "" Then
        Prompt = txtInput.Text
    Else
        Prompt = ""
    End If
    Unload Me
End Function
```

Called like:

```
strMyName = frmInputBox.Prompt("What's your name?", "Name Prompt")
```